# Will Scalable font work in Zebra MZ 320 printer

Tags: printing, label, zebra-printers, printers, thermal-printer

I am using CPCL commands to print labels in Zebra MZ 320 Printer. I want to use SCALABLE_TEXT command in my CPCL code. But the printer doesn't print anything. Will SCALABLE-TEXT command work in Zebra MZ 320 Printer? and how can i install .csf type of fonts in Zebra MZ 320 Printer?

Here is my CPCL code:

```
! 0 200 200 300 1
CENTER
SCALE-TEXT PLL_LAT.CSF 10 10 0 10 10 POINT FONT
FORM
PRINT
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That CPCL looks fine;  In fact, it looks like you took it directly from the CPCL manual: https://support.zebra.com/cpws/docs/comtec/PROMAN-CPCL_RevY.pdf .  You will want to make sure that the font that you are referencing is on the printer.  You can send the following command to see all files currently on the printer.  If you don't see PLL_LAT listed, then it is likely that the font is not on the printer:

! U1 getvar "file.dir"

- Notice that you must include a new line after this command, and that it is case-sensitive

This article explains how you can download additional fonts to the printer:
https://km.zebra.com/kb/index?page=answeropen&type=open&searchid=1362663129066&answerid=16777222&iqaction=5&url=https%3A%2F%2Fkm.zebra.com%2Fkb%2Findex%3Fpage%3Dcontent%26id%3DSO7889%26actp%3Dsearch%26viewlocale%3Den_US&highlightinfo=6292308,67,81#

Comment: I went through the link u have mentioned, Using Zebra Setup Utility i could download and install .mmf type files. how can i install .csf files to the printer?

Comment: @jason.zissman I see a font called ANGSANA.FNT, but when I print text with it the text won't print. Any idea?